# jQuery dropdown menu locked during click event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web-frontend

I am creating a web app that searches for events using an event api. I have a filter navbar where the user can enter certain filters (date-range, event category, distance, etc). I put a click handler on one of the navbar elements(category) so that it displays the hidden dropdown menu upon click. If the same navbar element is clicked again or any of its children (hidden dropdown elements), the dropdown menu should disappear. I used jQuery to change the text of the navbar element to the text of the category that was clicked from the dropdown menu. However, when I try to click the navbar element again, it is locked and I can't open it. I can't seem to find what is wrong with my code. Hopefully some additional eyes can help me spot it.

Here is the code.

```
<nav class="filter__container">
      <ul class="filter">
        <li class="filter__category">Category
          <div class="filter__category__choices">
            <p class="filter__category__choice">Art</p>
            <p class="filter__category__choice">Music</p>
            <p class="filter__category__choice">Sports</p>
            <p class="filter__category__choice">Festival</p>
            <p class="filter__category__choice">Miscellaneous</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="filter__submit">Apply Filters</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

const categoryFilter = $(".filter__category");
let categoryOpen = false;

categoryFilter.click((e) => {
    if(e.target !== categoryFilter[0]) {
      $(".filter__category").text($(e.target).text());
    }
    if(categoryOpen) {
      categoryPopup.slideUp();
      categoryOpen = false;
    }
    else {
      categoryPopup.slideDown();
      categoryOpen = true;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Instead of the `if/else`, have you tried `toggleSlide`? `categoryPopup.slideToggle();` By doing that you can get rid of the entire if/else statement and replace with that single line.